Is is possible to generate circularly polarized light using a rotating half-wave plate?
Let's assume that I have a laser beam with a frequency $\omega$ that is linearly polarized (say coming out of a laser diode). If I pass it through a half-wave plate (HWP), the light that is transmitted will still be linearly polarized, although with its axis rotated with respect to the initial one depending on the angle between the axis of the HWP and that of the polarization. Then, if I keep the input laser fixed, and put the HWP on a motorized mount that is rotating with an angular frequency $\Omega$, the polarization axis of the output beam will also be co-rotating at a frequency $\Omega$. Let's assume first $\Omega \ll \omega$.  What will happen if I start increasing the rotation frequency of the mount until $\Omega=\omega$? Will the output beam start behaving at that point like a circularly polarized beam?
From an EM point of view, I'm temped to say yes because that seems like the definition of a circularly polarized beam: the electric field vector will be tracing a circle in space as a function of time at the frequency of the beam.
However, from a QM, single photon point of view, this sounds wrong. If the photons are in the pure state $|R\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|H\rangle+i|V\rangle)$, then that state is clearly not $|H\rangle$,$|V\rangle$, $|+\rangle$ or $|-\rangle$, nor a mixed state. We can see that the density matrix $|R\rangle\langle R|$ is clearly different from that of any of the other states, namely it is an arrow pointing in the $y$-axis of the Bloch sphere. The output state of the beam after the rotating HWP will be an arrow that is tracing a circle along the $x-z$ plane of the Bloch sphere, but that is certainly not $|R\rangle$.
If I try to describe the polarization of a laser beam that is diagonally polarized ($|+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|H\rangle+|V\rangle)$), then it would be clearly wrong to describe it as being a mixture of $|H\rangle$ and $|V\rangle$. It is also clearly not a quick cyclical succession of $|H\rangle \rightarrow |V\rangle \rightarrow -|V\rangle \rightarrow -|H\rangle$. Using the same reasoning it sounds wrong to describe $|R\rangle$ as a mixture of $|H\rangle$ and $|V\rangle$, or even a quick cyclical succession of $|H\rangle \rightarrow |V\rangle \rightarrow -|H\rangle \rightarrow -|V\rangle$, but to me the classical EM picture does suggest that (perhaps naively). There has been a related question asked about circularly polarized light as viewed from a rotating frame, although it seems like there wasn't a clear answer back then.
My initial scenario is a macroscopic EM wave, but I think I should be able to make sense of if down to the single-photon level. In principle, I could attenuate the laser beam a lot and then perform quantum state tomography on the beam using single-photon detectors (or, if really necessary, jump to an SPDC setup and carry out a similar experiment with a true single-photon source). I'm also very curious about the $\Omega>\omega$ regime.
I understand that it might be too hard to reach such high rotational frequencies to carry out the experiment using visible light, but I guess in principle we could switch to lower-frequencies such as micro- or radio-waves and try a similar experiment so I'm thinking the answer shouldn't depend on $\omega$ in general.

Why not just use a quarter-wave plate to convert linear polarised light to circular (or elliptical)?

I know you can use a QWP! But this scenario is very interesting from a theoretical point of view.

How large of a portion of the half wave plate will be moving at less than the speed of light when it's rotating at Ω=ω?  I feel like that will be only on the order of a wavelength, so that you can't assume that the half wave plate behaves the same as a non-rotating half-wave plate.

Because a plate has polarized-by-light electrons, which have mass, rotation of the transmitted beam will occur.   Those electrons are in an accelerated state, of course, which rather complicates the QM picture of the 'photon' as they interact with its  polarization state.

True circular polarized light is just a mixture of multiple normal/linear polarized light.  According to QM if your laser emits one photon it will strike the plate either being reflected or transmitted .... when transmitted it will normal/linear polarized ..... which would just depend on angle of the plate.
Similarly you could just spin your laser and get the same effect.
Important point to realize here is all photons are linear/normal photons upon creation, if we mix 2 or more pure polarizations depending on the amount and angle of each one we can calculate a degree of circular polarization.

When you say all photons are linear upon creation, do you mean in this case specifically because it is a laser diode? Otherwise I think circularly polarized photons can exist on their own, and the state $|R\rangle$ is a pure state (see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/131623/can-a-single-photon-be-polarized-non-linearly). Is there a difference between $|R\rangle$ and a polarization state rotating on the $x-z$ plane of the Bloch sphere at the frequency of the light?

I would say it is true for all photon creation .... all the experiments on circular photons relate to many many photon sources and the separation of these sources into 2 linear polarizations.  In Rob's answer above he would "argue" based on the pendulum experiment ... but I guess the pendulum would still move with only linearly polarized light.  Many people are for the "true circular photon"  based on experiments/history from Fresnel (1800s) .... it may be also possible that we scientists could argue both with absolute proof never possible.

If you pass a single linearly polarized photon through a QWP at 45$^\circ$ and it gets transmitted, wouldn't we call that single output photon "circularly polarized"?

No it's completely rotated 45. if we pass it thru 8 plates x 45 we get the original orientation.

Through a QWP? That one turns linear to circular.

Linear and circular polarisation are just special cases of elliptical polarisation. You can express elliptical polarisation in a horizontal + vertical basis, or in a clockwise + anticlockwise basis. Neither basis is more fundamental.

@Danyel per Wikipedia half wave plate we get a full 90 degree rotation if orientation is 45 to the crystal optical axis. My understanding of the quarter wave plate is it outputs 2 polarizations which when superimposed can be described as circular ..... but its just a description of 2 polarizations. If we inject single photons some will be one polarization and some the other, random.

@PhysicsDave a QWP is just a unitary transformation, we can look up its Jones matrix. At $\theta=45^\circ$, $\hat{U}_{QWP}(\theta=45^\circ)|H\rangle = |R\rangle$

For simplicity, let's consider the two dimensional Hilbert space representing the polarization of the photon. Macroscopically, the polarization of light is represented by Poincare Sphere, which is the same thing of the Bloch sphere, so the last is enough to organize the argument.
The action of a linear polarizer is represented by a projector. When vertically oriented, it will be $P_V = |V\rangle\!\langle V|$. In Bloch sphere
$$
P_V = \frac 12 \left( \mathbb I + Z\right)
$$
Where $Z$ is the z Pauli matrix. The state after the polarizer is (unormalized) $|\psi'\rangle\propto P_V |\psi\rangle$. Now let's consider any other direction on ZX plane. It could be parametrized by an angle $\theta$ and we could write
$$
P_\theta = \frac 12 \left ( \mathbb I \cos (\theta) Z + \sin (\theta) X \right ).
$$
If $\theta =0$, we recover $P_V$, i.e., the polarization in the vertical direction. Directions in the Bloch sphere are not the same as directions in space. The state $|H\rangle$ is orthogonal to $|V\rangle$, but it is given by $\theta = \pi$ in the formula above, i.e., antiparallel to the Bloch vector of $|V\rangle$. If $|V\rangle$ and $H\rangle$ represent two perpendicular directions on the plane of polarization, any linear polarization could be written as a combination of these two, like $|P_\phi\rangle = \cos(\phi)|V\rangle + \sin(\phi)|H\rangle$. The angle $\phi$ are related to directions in the polarization plane, perpendicular of direction of propagation, so it represents direction in real space. To connect it with Bloch sphere, we could decompose the projector associated to the state above, and what we would find is that $\theta=2\phi$. From now and on, all the description could be done in Bloch sphere.

Let's consider that our linear polarizer is rotating in a plane, parallel to that generated by $|V\rangle,|H\rangle$. For simplicity, the angle starts at $\phi(0)=0$ (vertical) and it rotates with constant angular velocity so $\phi(t)= \Omega t$. The  projector at time t would be
$$
P_\Omega = \left (\mathbb I + \cos{(\Omega t)}Z + \sin{(\Omega t)} X \right)
$$
And the state after the polarizer $P_\Omega |\psi\rangle \cos{(\Omega t)} \propto |V\rangle + \sin{(\Omega t)} |H\rangle$.
Look that all states of linear polarization in the  polarization plane could and would be accessed, at some time t. But we will never access any state of circular polarization, like $|V\rangle + i|H\rangle$. In the Bloch sphere, this is more evident: we never leave the zx plane, so we couldn't access the whole Bloch sphere. A circular polarizer would be
$$
P_R = \frac 12 \left ( \mathbb I + Y\right ),
$$
Never achieved by $P_\Omega$, no matter what frequency we set neither how many time we wait.

It seems that we could generate a rotating polarized wave with rotating linear polarizer, but why it shouldn't be a circular polarized wave? By the reason that in circular polarization we have dephasing between the components of the electric field, something that we could not produce with rotations of the linear polarizer. You'll produce a rotating polarization, but where both components of $E_x$ and $E_y$ are always in phase, and it could not be called circular polarization, simple because it doesn't fit its definition and doesn't share its properties.
If you want to connect it with classical electromagnetism, you should work with the Stokes parameters, defined as
$$
\begin{aligned}
S_0 &= E_x^2 + E_y^2\\
S_1 &= E_x^2 - E_y^2\\
S_2 &= 2E_xE_y\cos\delta\\
S_3 &= 2E_xE_y\sin\delta
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\delta$ is the dephasing aforementioned. Look that if you produce linear polarized light, $\delta = 0$,  doesn't matter if you rotate the direction of polarization, which in this case is to change $E_x$ and $E_y$ in phase.
To match Bloch and Poincare sphere, look that $S_1$ corresponds to $-Z$, $S_2$ corresponds to $X$ and $S_3$ to $Y$.

Note that in my proposed scenario I'm using a rotating HWP, which is a unitary transform, not the rotating LP (with is projective) that you used. Regardless, I checked the definition of circular polarization and it is an EM field where the wave has a constant magnitude and is rotating at a constant rate in a plane perpendicular to the direction of the wave. I think that fits the definition of our funny rotating linear polarization.

1. How does a polarizer work?
Designed for the frequency range of the photons to be influenced, ideally 50 % of the photons pass through the polarizer (for photons with frequencies above and below the ideal frequency, either the transmission rate decreases or the photons are not all fully polarized). How do I influence a beam of photons at a polarizer?
To get a clearer idea here, I remind you of the experimental setup in which all photons are blocked behind two crossed polarizers. If you move a third polarizer at 45° between the crossed polarizers, light comes out again.
This only leads to the conclusion that the edges of the slits of the polarizers - or more precisely their surface electrons - interact with the electric field component of the photon and align it parallel to the slits. Although I am not familiar with this and do not rule out the interaction of the magnetic field component or a 90° alignment to the slit - but this does not change the fact that unpolarized photons are subject to a rotation of their E and B field components at the slit.
2. How do I obtain a torque for the field components of the photon?
In my opinion, there are - at least - two possibilities:

When photons are emitted from a rotating molecule, the emission should carry some of the torque of the molecule - the E and B components of the photon rotate. In the case of the molecule, this is most likely to be elliptical circular.
When passing through a crystal structure, there are structures that are characterized by a periodicity of their structure that exactly matches the resonance of the E and B field components of photons of excellent frequencies. And among these structures, there are some whose crystal lattice is not completely cubic, but is oriented in such a way that the photons receive a twist.


Danyel: Is is possible to generate circularly polarized light using a rotating half-wave plate?

If you follow the above, then clearly yes. A rotation of the influencing medium will give the transmitting photons a twist.
TL;DR
I deliberately write about a twist, not a spin. The spin of the subatomic particles is clearly to be seen in relation to the orientation of the magnetic field component of the electron and proton. The entire spintronics is based on magnetic phenomains. Talking about a spin in the photon is very misleading. There is a chirality of the sequence of the field components of the photon, and this is opposite for photons made from electrons and positrons.
TL;DR
